Is there a way to send multiple HTTP/2 requests concurrently on a single connection in Rust?
I am sending GET requests to a url like this:
use bytes::Bytes;
use http_body_util::Empty;
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use hyper_util::{client::legacy::Client, rt::TokioExecutor};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{task::JoinHandle, time::Instant};

async fn connection_request(
    requests: u32,
    client: Arc<
        Client<HttpsConnector<hyper_util::client::legacy::connect::HttpConnector>, Empty<Bytes>>,
    >,
) {
    for _ in 0..requests {
        if let Ok(_) = client
            .get("https://www.example.com/".parse().unwrap())
            .await
        {
            //  println!("status: {}", res.status());
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread")]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let requests = 100;
    let https = HttpsConnector::new();

    let client = Client::builder(TokioExecutor::new())
        .pool_idle_timeout(Duration::from_secs(30))
        .build::<_, Empty<Bytes>>(https);
    let shared_client = Arc::new(client);

    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    let total_connections = 50;

    let start = Instant::now();

    for _ in 0..total_connections {
        let client_clone = shared_client.clone();
        handles.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            connection_request(requests / total_connections, client_clone).await;
        }));
    }

    for handle in handles {
        let _ = handle.await;
    }

    let elapsed = start.elapsed();
    println!("Total time: {:?}", elapsed);

    Ok(())
}

I'm using hyper legacy, the code provided opens a new connection for every iteration of the loop, I want it to use the same connection (i.e only one handshake) and then send requests concurrently, thought using Arc would help but it didn't in this case, also tried to use the new hyper low level crate but its documentation is incomplete

How would this even be physically possible?

It doesn't look like the hyper client supports this. It does look like it might be possible if you implement your own connection pooling to make use of http 1 pipeline/http2 multiplexing.

@Andrew: "How would this even be physically possible?"  - I'm assuming that with "physically" you mean from what happens on the wire. Contrary to HTTP/1 where requests can only be sent sequentually, HTTP/2 (which is supported by Hyper) has the concept of concurrent requests within the same connection, because multiple messages can be interleaved.

If you want to explicitly use http2, you don't need connection pooling, so much as some way of matching connections to domains. How to do that will depend on the context of the application. Are all the requests to a single domain or multiple, and is this a long lived connection, or just for a single transaction.

ok, that makes sense. thanks.
